# Visual Studio will not debug any of my projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and the same problem is also occurring with Visual Studio 2010. Basically, when I press F5, Visual studio attempts to run and debug the project, it then plays the "Exclamation" sound  like one from a message box; and then it stops debugging the project. Nothing is said in my output window, it's as if nothing happened. I've looked everywhere on the internet but I haven't found anything!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you build the project only (Build -> Build Solution) does it give you any errors/warnings?

Comment: Is the project even debuggable?

Comment: @swinkel Not at all, it builds it just fine.

Comment: @ZachM. Yes, it worked before, and as I said above, this is happening with all of my projects, they are all debuggable. This problem is even occurring when I create a brand new project

Comment: Did you try to restart Visual Studio?

Comment: @Randy plenty of times

Comment: Can you manually attach to the process (CTRL+ALT+P)? Do the breakpoints appear filled-in (not hollow/outlines) when you do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might have a corrupt install. I would suggest trying to repair the installation.

Comment: How? Both visual studios have worked perfectly since day 1, I don't see why it would suddenly just corrupt itself? But I'll try the repair anyway, just to double check I suppose.

Comment: It appears that I have a trojan and I suspect that this is what is causing VS to not function, I am currently scanning my pc and I keep getting 2 error messages: "iexplore.exe" and "WerFault.exe" application error: The exception unknown software exception occured in the application. So I think I will try to get rid of this god damn virus first and then try Visual studio again.

Comment: Yikes! Good luck getting rid of it!

Comment: Thanks, I'll need it! I'll let you know further once I've (hopefully) gotten rid of the malware.

Comment: Update: Okay this is weird, but some of the trojan files got removed, and suddenly visual studio starts debugging again, how does that work? That is so weird...

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: Let's just hope it remains this way!